# get controller webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my project, there are multiple controllers. My "books"-controller has multiple methods without any parameters.

so I changed the default mapping from:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "get" }
        );
```

now actually this is only the case for the books controller... other controllers should be handled like the first mapping...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you are asking but this might work,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BooksApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/books/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="books", id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "get" }
        );
```